# Why is OP_XOR disabled? Are there any forks on which it has been enabled?

Tags: transactions, script, transaction-verification, opcodes

Why is `OP_XOR` [disabled](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Transaction_with_a_message)?

Are there any forks on which it has been enabled?

Are there any plans to enable it?

Perhaps [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/48720/34190) is the answer, still perhaps there is another reason for the bitwise logic functions being disabled...

Comment: I think the answer you linked does answer your question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I can tell:

OP_XOR is not implemented in BTC.

OP_XOR is [implemented](https://github.com/schancel/spec/blob/5e9319028e85321c24eac9fe4b47e60c42b315bc/may-2018-reenabled-opcodes.md#op_xor) [on BitcoinABC](https://reviews.bitcoinabc.org/D1090) and [subsequent forks](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/technical/infographic-map-bitcoin-forks) of that (e.g. [BCH](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/blob/master/packages/bitcore-lib-cash/lib/script/interpreter.js#L1322), [BSV](https://wiki.bitcoinsv.io/index.php/Opcodes_used_in_Bitcoin_Script)), but P2SH has been depreciated on [BSV](https://wiki.bitcoinsv.io/index.php/Complex_Script_Options):

> P2SH – Pay to Script Hash (deprecated with the Genesis upgrade after
> Feb 4th 2020)

*from wiki.bitcoinsv.io*

Comment: P2SH can be implemented with existing opcodes in the Script https://xiaohuiliu.medium.com/sun-rising-p2sh-7ebfca9283aa.